# How to fix the position of a logo regardless of the zoom?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a shiny app and I have two logos in it. Suppose that these logos are:

[USGS logo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/USGS_logo_green.svg/2000px-USGS_logo_green.svg.png); and

[RStudio logo](http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png)

You can find the two logos in the [**www folder here**](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d909ypivnotjd4c/AAAiAbfMcXgTbNLAZe6kMo7ya?dl=0).

I want to have the Rstudio logo on the top left and and the USGS logo on the top right. I did this using the code below

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
fluidRow(
column(4,   
       tags$img(height = 150,
                width  = 400, 
                src    = "RStudio.png")),
column(5),
column(3,   
       tags$img(height = 150,
                width  = 400, 
                src    = "USGS.png"))))
server <- function(input,output){}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It worked fine if the zoom is 100%, However, if I zoom out (i.e. zoom 75%) the USGS logo is displaced to the left and it doesn't remain as it should be in the far top right.

[image]

When I'm using ggplot2, I find that all plots are being re-adjusted whenever I zoom in or I zoom out. Is it possible to have the same with the legend, regardless of zooming in or out it will remain in the same place?

Comment: You can experiment with different layout system listed on this page: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html#grid-layouts-in-depth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the green logo is not actually told to go on the right side.  By default, everything in laid out left-to-right.  What your layout does is say "put the green logo in the last 3/12ths of the screen horizontally", so it's being put in the right-most quarter, BUT it's starting to count from the left.  To prove this, change the width to something smaller, like 200, and you'll see that the green logo's left coordinate is the same as before, but because the width is smaller, its right coordinate is not as far right as before.

So what you want to do is tell the page to actually put the image on the right, not just "in the right 25% of the page".  Add `style = "float: right",` to the arguments of the `tags$img()`